Looking for an 80s or early 90s (1990) giant space robot comic
It featured big robots in space.
I only remember fragments of it. The robots were in space, with oversized forearms and shins. They had an energy weapon on one of the forearm (or both, don't remember) and had also some kind of spike/blade at the end of said forearm.
In one issue, they were talking about a "Maginot Line" and in another there was a feline-like, human-sized character, named "Pun-Ra" or something like that.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read this?  Was it black-and-white or colour?

Shogun Warriors? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogun_Warriors_(comics)

@DavidW it was colour.

@KlausÆ.Mogensen nope. It was a more modern publication.
